# Are lawyers allowed to contact potential clients?

Tags: lawyer, legal-representation, misconduct

Would it be inappropriate for a lawyer to proactively find/contact people who might need legal representation and offer them their services? Would it be against any code of conduct or similar?

The lawyer could have learned about someone in need for legal representation through:

- public media and published court judgments
- non-lawyer friends
- lawyers in informal context (friends)
- lawyers in business / professional networking context

Comment: This happens all the time, which is where the term "ambulance chaser" comes from (although actual ambulance chasing/solicitation at a disaster site *is* against the rules of professional conduct of the ABA in the US, but California which has its own rules). There are a lot of "legal ads" which would be "proactively finding people" that run on TV, internet, paper, etc. I don't see anything inappropriate about proactively getting business... What jurisdiction are you talking about?

Comment: @RonBeyer I'd expect the rules around that be similar in most jurisdictions. If not true, let's focus on English-centric-common-law ones. Ultimately New Zealand. And, I guess that would still be inappropriate in some cases if information about potential client is obtained through professional networking — on either or both the provider or the recipient of such information.

Comment: My guess would be that, even in English-speaking jurisdictions, the American freedom-of-speech-based rules will be very different from the English-style reduction of-unnecessary-litigation-based ones. And what the profession considers inappropriate may be largely opinion-based. I won't VTC, but I doubt you'll get helpfull answers without tightening this up

Comment: @RonBeyer the [wikipedia article for "ambulance chasing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambulance_chasing) says it is illegal. I think the ads are a different case, they are targeted to the general public, not specifically victims of a disaster.

Comment: @TimLymington "_what the profession considers inappropriate_" will be codified by bar associations (or even in statutes), be it opinion based or not. So this question is mostly about what codes of conduct say, assuming they say or imply similar things regarding the matter in common law jurisdictions all over the world.

Comment: @Greendrake The relevant ethical rules and statutes vary quite a bit from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. For example, the rules in CO, NY, CA, OH and UK are all different. There is not really even a majority rule and this is a rapidly evolving area where different states and countries are changing their rules (usually to permit more marketing) on a regular basis. Civil law countries are more uniform but differ from common law country approaches. Voted to close as too broad.